# How to filter for child properties in crowdstrike api using curl?

Tags: curl

Here is just an example of curl using filter.

```
"https://api.crowdstrike.com/devices/queries/devices/v1" \
 -H 'Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGci...xYg1NNI' \
 -H 'Accept: application/json' \
 -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
 --data-urlencode "filter=product_type_desc:'Workstation'"
```

I can filter by `product_type_desc`. But how to filter if the property is in the child field? Here is the sample resources. I want to filter from the `policy_type` field. How do I write the filter parameters?

```
"resources": [
    {
        "product_type_desc":"Workstation",
        "device_policies": {
            "mobile": {
                "policy_type": "mobile",
            }
        },
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by using a period for each child element. Here's the sample code.

```
"https://api.crowdstrike.com/devices/queries/devices/v1" \
 -H 'Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGci...xYg1NNI' \
 -H 'Accept: application/json' \
 -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
 --data-urlencode "filter=device_policies.mobile.policy_type:'mobile'"
```